# how to call a soap webservice made in delphi (on apache) from curl

Tags: delphi, curl, soap

In Delphi 11 Alexandria, I created a simple SOAP webservice using `File->New->Soap Server`. I asked to create the demo interfaces, I have built the project, corrected Apache conf, and I have copied the DLL inside Apache's module directory.

So, if I request:

http://127.0.0.1:81/xyz/mod_webbroker.dll

I get into the page where I see the interfaces, and I can view the WSDL.

Now, I would like to try to call the demo function (`echoDouble`) from PHP using curl.

How do I know what address I should use?

I tried:

http://127.0.0.1:81/xyz/wsdl/IMyService/echoDouble/

But it's not working.

Any help?

Comment: Use `soapui` test.

Comment: Thank you I will try that soon. But isn't there a standard URL Delphi uses? I cannot find it in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand my doubts now. I have always used "Datasnap rest application" but now I am trying "SOAP server application", that is why I cannot find the correct URL, because they work different. When using "Datasnap rest application" you need to go to a specific URL to get the function but SOAP works different, the base URL is always this (in my case):
http://127.0.0.1:81/xyz/wsdl/IMyService/
Sorry for that, I will switch back to "Datasnap rest application"